# Confusion with multiplication when determining the order of $\frac34+\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group

> Determine the order of $\frac34+\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

The order of an element is the smallest $n$ for which in this case $n(\frac34+\Bbb Z )=e= \Bbb Z$ since the binary operation here is addition.

Now my question is that why isn’t this $n$ being multiplied to $\Bbb Z$, but only to the fraction?

So $1 (\frac34+\Bbb Z ) = (\frac34+\Bbb Z ) $ and $2 (\frac34+\Bbb Z ) =\frac64+\Bbb Z = \frac34 + \Bbb Z$, $3(\frac34+\Bbb Z )= \frac94 + \Bbb Z.$

And lastly $4(\frac34+\Bbb Z )= 3+ \Bbb Z = \Bbb Z$. So $4$ would be the order.

I’m not sure if it’s wrong notation but why isn’t for example $$2 (\frac34+\Bbb Z )  = \frac64+2\Bbb Z$$ instead of $$2 (\frac34+\Bbb Z )  = \frac64+\Bbb Z ?$$

Comment: Consider the definition of multiplying a coset by an integer,

Comment: My book doesn’t seem to contain one...

Comment: Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z},$ then $n(a+\mathbb{Z})=na+\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ is a quotient ring, where $\frac{m}{n}\sim\frac{m'}{n'}$, i.e $\frac{m}{n}+\Bbb{Z}=\frac{m'}{n'}+\Bbb{Z}$ iff $\frac{m}{n}=k+\frac{m'}{n'}$ where $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. The way you add (and therefore multiply by an integer) by definition is $(\frac{m}{n}+\Bbb{Z})+(\frac{m'}{n'}+\Bbb{Z})=\frac{m'}{n'}+\frac{m}{n}+\Bbb{Z}$. That's how we define addition - and hence multiplication by an integer.